# switch observable based on previous observable

Tags: observable, angular-observable

I have an observable A which returns boolean observable and based on the value of observable A I need to call wither observable B or C

```
observableA = of(true);

observableB(): observable<string> {
}

observableC(): observable<string> {
}

function value () {
   return observableA.pipe(map(value => {
     if(value) {
      return observableB();
     } else {
      return observableC();
    }

}))
}
```

Comment: @khizer's answer resubscribes on your base observables every time the truth value changes, is that okay? Are your B and C observables hot?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to differentiate which observable to call based on truthy value.
Example shown below

- **case => true => multiple item by 10**
- **case => false => multiple item by 20**

```
import { of, Subject } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

const observableInvokeOnTruthy$ = of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
const observableInvokeOnFalsy$ = of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
const emitValuesSubject$ = new Subject();

emitValuesSubject$.subscribe(response => {
  if (response) {
    console.log("TRUTHY VALUE:");
    observableInvokeOnTruthy$
      .pipe(
        map(item => {
          return item * 10;
        })
      )
      .subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result);
      });
  } else {
    console.log("FALSY VALUE:");
    observableInvokeOnFalsy$
      .pipe(
        map(item => {
          return item * 20;
        })
      )
      .subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result);
      });
  }
});

emitValuesSubject$.next(false);
emitValuesSubject$.next(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `switchMap` operator instead of `map`:

```
function value () {
   return observableA.pipe(switchMap(value => {
     if(value) {
      return observableB();
     } else {
      return observableC();
    }

}))
```